# Need to pass parameters for library to compile simple program

Tags: opencv, installation, g++, shared-libraries

This looks to be an easy one but I am not able to get it through.

So, I have installed OpenCV library and the executables are present at

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib

apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/AGV/Vision$  ls /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib
cmake                                           libopencv_fuzzy.dylib                           
libopencv_saliency.dylib
libade.a                                        libopencv_gapi.4.5.3.dylib                      
libopencv_sfm.4.5.3.dylib
libcorrespondence.a                             libopencv_gapi.4.5.dylib                        
libopencv_sfm.4.5.dylib
....
....
```

And my $PATH variable looks like this:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/AGV/Vision$  echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/opencv/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

If you notice, the path to installed libraries is part of the $PATH variable. Problem is that when I compile a simple program of OpenCV library, it says it can not find the file which seems frustrating.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
int main() {
}
```

Error I get is:

```
apple@Apples-MacBook-Air.local:~/AGV/Vision$  g++ agv.cpp
agv.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/highgui.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

If I have added the library path to $PATH variable, shouldn't g++ take the libraries from that path and proceed?

What am I missing here?

Comment: g++ does not look at the PATH, you have to use `g++ -I/path/to/opencv/headers` (and similar for the libs later, `-L/path/to/libs`

Comment: @berak Thanks for your reply. That is how I am resolving it currently. Since there are many libraries involved with `opencv`, I would like some better alternative to that.